# Do the EXP UP and AP UP passives affect just the character or the entire party?

Tags: ios, final-fantasy-5

The iOS version of Final Fantasy V has the same bonus classes that the GBA had, among which is the [Cannoneer](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cannoneer_%28Final_Fantasy_V%29), who can gain the passive ability to earn XP at a faster rate, as well as the Oracle who gets a passive that increases AP gain.

My questions: 
 1. Do these abilities apply to just the character equipping them, or to the whole party?
 2. Are these passives granted to the Freelancer and Mime jobs upon mastery of Cannoneer and Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) These abilities apply only to the character who has them equipped.

2) **No**, Mime and Freelancer only inherit what are usually called "innate abilities" - that is, abilities that the class gets when used even without equipping them.  For example, Ninja automatically has Dual-Wield even without equipping it.  Once you've learned it properly, your Mimes and Freelancers get it automatically without equipping it.

Comment: Honestly, by the time I unlocked these jobs I couldn't care less about exp and it took me maybe a couple of hours at the most to get the AP skill on all four characters.